# ModelAndView returns no data to jsp views

Tags: java, jsp, netbeans, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC 3, NetBeans

I have the following model,

```
public class MarketPlace {

private String status;

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

private String category;

public String getCategory() {
    return category;
```

}

and this is my controller method,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ListApplication.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView ShowForm(HttpServletRequest request) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("ListApplication"); 
    mav.addObject("apps", marketPlaceService.listApplications());
    return mav;
}
```

the marketPlaceService.listApplications() method returns List. 
and here is my view,

```
<c:forEach items="${apps}" var="item">
<p>Template Name: ${item.templateName}</p>
<p>Description: ${item.description}</p>
<p>Category: ${item.category}</p>
<p><img " src="${item.templateLogo}" border="0" alt="" /></div></td></p>
<br><br>
</c:forEach>
```

From debugging I see at least 20 records in the list but the jsp view shows nothing.

**Edit**:
Interestingly, this code is working,

```
 protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(
        HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("ListApplication");
    mav.addObject("apps", marketPlaceService.listApplications());
    return mav;
}
```

Can anyone tells me the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is answer that I found so fast,

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/ListApplication.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String ShowForm(HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap m) {        
    m.addObject("apps", marketPlaceService.listApplications());
    return "ListApplication";
}
```

Any further improvement is welcome. However, addObject is seems to be deprecated, any alternative?

Answer (score 2):

Your `<img>` tag is badly formed:

```
<img " src="${item.templateLogo}" border="0" alt="" />
```

Should be:

```
<img src="${item.templateLogo}" border="0" alt="" />
```

You also have `</div></td>` after the `<img/>` tag which shouldn't be there.

Not sure about the template name, description and category though... Maybe the typo in the `<img>` tag is causing the jstl to not be filtered correctly.

Comment: Thanks. But it won't work. Even if I use noting is rendered,   <c:forEach items="${apps}" var="item">
                                           123
                                        </c:forEach>